# What is this text over the door?

Tags: hebrew, language

I'm adding this post for Albert, who posted this in Biblical Hermeneutics.  His question:

> Hi i got some people rent a house, and they put this signs which i think is hebrew on the top of the entry door on the other door that goes into the patio, what does this mean/is use for?

Apparently this is niphal from יָלַד and means *born*, but I don't know its purpose. Is this a Jewish custom?

[image]

Comment: Can you ask them?

Comment: It could be "Neileich", translated into something like "let's go", but I don't know of any jewish symbolism of such a thing

Comment: What about a Christian claim about the birth of Yoshke?

Comment: Apparently it's personal and only the writer can answer.

Comment: a star is born? I give this birth 2 stars?

Comment: The nif'al of "give birth" is usually נולד. The spelling נלד usually means "let's give birth" or "we'll give birth". In any event, the answer to your question is _probably_ No.

Comment: So, whether the root is יָלַד or  הָלַךְ, it is apparently imperfect,1st person plural: 
      דֶּ֚רֶךְ שְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֔ים נֵלֵ֖ךְ בַּמִּדְבָּ֑ר וְזָבַ֙חְנוּ֙ לַֽיהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֵ֔ינוּ כַּאֲשֶׁ֖ר יֹאמַ֥ר אֵלֵֽינוּ׃
(Exodus 8:23, MT)